# Theoretical and Operational bandwidth of different network technologies

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bandwidth

There are so many webpages where these information can be found. Unfortunately, there are so much differences among them that it is really confusing. I need a reliable source(s) where I can find up-to-date theoretical and operational maximum and minimum data transfer rate or bandwidth of Copper Cable, Optical Fiber networks, WiFi, WiMax/ 4G LTE. Thanks.

Comment: Forouzan: Data Communications and Networking is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all respect, your question - as asked - is impossible to answer in totality.  Your question mixes physical mediums (copper cable, optical fiber, "WiFi") with communication protocol standards (WiMAX/4G LTE).

Advances in technology and engineer mean the our methods of transmitting data across various mediums have constantly improved.

For example, consider the original Ethernet standard. If I can bang a spoon on a copper wire, my bandwidth is a lot lower than if I use the original Ethernet IEEE 802.3 standard. I'd have even better bandwidth if I used the IEEE 802.3 (14) standard.

Similar arguments can be applied to "WiFi" (see 802.11a, 802.11b, 802.11g, etc) and to fiber.

WiMax (IEEE 802.16) and 4GLTE are standards - not physical mediums. But as I show above, standards change as new methods of data compression and transmission are created/discovered.

One might say, "But wait! There has to be a physical limit on much data you can send via fiber or copper." Well, no - it depends.  How are you transmitting your data? With what protocol? Over what distance?

Comment: Shannon–Hartley theorem states a limit.